# Geoserver style with condition

Tags: styles, geoserver, sld

How can I use a different image (OnlineResource) depending on the attribute value?
I have a feature with a 'number' attribute, I need to do something like:
if number = 0 then OnlineResource = image 1
else OnlineResource = image 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two [rule](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/reference/rules.html)s with [filter](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/reference/filters.html#sld-reference-filters)s in your SLD:

```
  <FeatureTypeStyle>
     <Rule>
       <Name>local-road</Name>
       <ogc:Filter>
         <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
           <ogc:PropertyName>type</ogc:PropertyName>
           <ogc:Literal>local-road</ogc:Literal>
         </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
       </ogc:Filter>
       <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#009933</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">2</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer>
     </Rule>
     <Rule>
       <Name>secondary</Name>
       <ogc:Filter>
         <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
           <ogc:PropertyName>type</ogc:PropertyName>
           <ogc:Literal>secondary</ogc:Literal>
         </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
       </ogc:Filter>
       <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#0055CC</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">3</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer>
     </Rule>
   </FeatureTypeStyle>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try creating a rule with the  tag (empty) instead of the ogc:Filter ... </ogc:Filter> tag

[An else rule applies when, after scale and filters are applied, no other rule applies](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/ysld/reference/rules.html#:%7E:text=An%20else%20rule%20applies%20when%2C%20after%20scale%20and%20filters%20are%20applied%2C%20no%20other%20rule%20applies.).

```
  <FeatureTypeStyle>
     <Rule>
       <Name>local-road</Name>
       <ogc:Filter>
         <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
           <ogc:PropertyName>number</ogc:PropertyName>
           <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
         </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
       </ogc:Filter>
      <PointSymbolizer>
        <Graphic>
            ...
        </Graphic>
      </PointSymbolizer>
     </Rule>
     <!-- this is the else rule -->
     <Rule>
       <Name>else</Name>
        <ElseFilter></ElseFilter>
          <PointSymbolizer>
            <Graphic>
              ...
            </Graphic>
          </PointSymbolizer>
     </Rule>
   </FeatureTypeStyle>
```